# Automatically update monitoring website with Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot

I have a Java application which I start using Spring Boot and I have added a .jsp file providing a website to monitor the status of the application.

Is there a possibility to update the website automatically when the application changes its state? Currently, I have to press F5 or use an auto refresh plugin. However, I have the impression that there should be techniques allowing this without reloading the complete website every few seconds.

I do not even know what to google for, so any hint would be really helpful.

Comment: High kap.  This is not really java or spring-boot specific. The question would be what you do expect when you say "changes it state". Meaning when you want to push some information from your app to the client I suggest you to have a look at WebSockets. If you mean you want to notify your user that the app crashed or something then I think this will not be possible. How should an app that crashed notify a user? You will need to implement something else for this.

Comment: Well, change state would mean "return something different for the same endpoint". I was looking for an active variant of long polling. It is not really required to check for updated state every `x` seconds when the update occurs only after a few minutes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I continued searching and found a solution. In HTML5 there is introduced [Server-sent Events](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Server-sent_events) (SSE) which allow to send data from the server back to any client currently viewing the website. Some JavaScript can then be used to update the website accordingly.

It is very simple to use the SSE within Spring Boot:

The `@Controller` has to store a list of `SseEmitter` and send any updated data to each of these emitters. Also another request mapping is necessary to allow clients to register themselves.

```
private final List<SseEmitter> sseEmitter = new LinkedList<>();

@RequestMapping (path = "/register", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public SseEmitter register() throws IOException {
    log.info("Registering a stream.");

    SseEmitter emitter = new SseEmitter();

    synchronized (sseEmitter) {
        sseEmitter.add(emitter);
    }
    emitter.onCompletion(() -> sseEmitter.remove(emitter));

    return emitter;
}
```

The .jsp file needs some JavaScript to register itself. The function should be executed when the page loads.

```
var connect = function () {
    var source = new EventSource('/register');
    // Reconnect if the connection fails
    source.addEventListener('error', function (e) {
        console.log('Disconnected.');
        if (e.readyState == EventSource.CLOSED) {
            connected = false;
            connect();
        }
    }, false);
};
```

An update can be requested by the `@Controller` by sending data to all known emitters:

```
synchronized (sseEmitter) {
    sseEmitter.forEach((SseEmitter emitter) -> {
        try {
            emitter.send(state, MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            emitter.complete();
            sseEmitter.remove(emitter);
        }
    });
}
```

Finally, the website accepts the message and handles it. The following has also to be added to the `connect()` function:

```
source.addEventListener('message', function (e) {
    var state = JSON.parse(e.data);
    console.log("New state: " + state.text);
    var element = document.getElementById("state");
    element.innerHTML = state.text;
}, false);
```

I have uploaded a simple example project to [GitHub](https://github.com/kappmeier/spring-boot-examples/tree/master/tomcat-jsp-sse).

Comment: Use WebSockets instead

Answer (score 0):

From spring boot 1.3 there is new tool ***spring-devtools***.

https://spring.io/blog/2015/06/17/devtools-in-spring-boot-1-3

There is browser extensions which is freely available for Chrome, Firefox and Safari from http://livereload.com.